# How to get my Localhost url by default in flask app?

Tags: flask

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
    #   cloudinary.config(cloud_name = os.getenv('CLOUD_NAME'), api_key=os.getenv('API_KEY'),
    #     api_secret=os.getenv('API_SECRET'))
    upload_result = None
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html')
```

I am not getting my flask app in localhost . When I manually type '/upload' in URL then it works . How to get it automatically by default. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify "/upload" in app.route then it will work only if you send GET request to /upload.

Try using "/" instead of "/upload":

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
    upload_result = None
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: it worked.But when I deployed it to Heroku, an Internal Server 500 Occures

Comment: Glad to read it worked!
Please remember to choose it as final answer and / or upvote it.
If you have more questions please start a new one.